# How to re-alert Monit?

Tags: monitoring, monit

I'm currently working on a Monit config that alerts when a certain status reached the threshold.

```
check program check_something with path "/root/scripts/check_something.sh"
  if status > 10 then alert
```

The above config works well and I would like to add a recurring alert everyday if the status is still more than the threshold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to solve the issue by adding `timeout` of 86400 seconds which is equivalent to 1 day.

```
check program check_something with path "/root/scripts/check_something.sh"
  if status > 10 then alert
  if status > 10 with timeout 86400 seconds then alert
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use [setting an error reminder](http://mmonit.com/monit/documentation/monit.html#setting_an_error_reminder).

First, grab the duration of your cycle. It's usually in the `/etc/monitrc` file with `set daemon n` where n is the duration.

Then, if you want one every day, calculate the number of cycles per day:

```
number_cyle_per_day = 24*60*60/n
```

And finally, use it in your script :

```
check program check_something with path "/root/scripts/check_something.sh"
  if status > 10 then alert reminder on number_cyle_per_day cycles
```

it should work like this!

Comment: Hi Pierre, thanks for the response, I've tried the solution and I've came up with 1400 cycles/day. This throws an error saying that the maximum cycle is 64.

Comment: Hum, I didn't know that.. Maybe, if you have just this test, you can reduce the duration of your cycle? Or maybe add a line `if status > 10  for 1400 cycles then alert`(but I guess there is the same limitation..)